# .htacces решение для "Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta" и 301 редирект для www

Tags: .htaccess

Нашел [решение](http://www.validatethis.co.uk/news/fix-bad-value-x-ua-compatible-once-and-for-all/) для устранения ошибки "*A “meta” element with an “http-equiv” attribute whose value is “X-UA-Compatible” must have a “content” attribute with the value “IE=edge”.*" в валидаторе. Который возникает если есть вот эта строчка:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Написано, что необходимо добавить в файл .htaccess вот это:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        BrowserMatch MSIE ie
        Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

При этом ошибка не исчезает.

И второй вопрос. Чтоб не было склейки, необходимо прописать следующее:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

или

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Сейчас эта часть файла выглядит так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^roocms
    RewriteRule (.*) http://jane.co.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://jane.co.ua/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Если заменить эту строчку `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^roocms` на эту `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.$ [NC]` будут ли проблемы?

Comment: Привет. Спасибо, что для .htaccess использовал мое решение с хабра. Приятно. Касательно склейки... Да можно вообще весь блок убрать и не будет склейки... Ну и в 4 строке ошибка... ^roocms надо в твоем случае заменить на ^jane